# Can a text file be outputted to the local filesystem directly from Spark?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

With an RDD, I can output `rdd.saveAsTextFile('directory')` which saves the file in `hdfs://directory`. Can the text file be save directly to a directory on the local filesystem (i.e. `directory`)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save a spark RDD to the local file system using Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31239161/save-a-spark-rdd-to-the-local-file-system-using-java)

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can... since the saveAsTextFile('directory') will save as many files as your partitioners, you first neeed to merge the files before you copy to local (unless you wish to copy each file into local). Therefore first call

```
FileUtil.copyMerge(sourceFileSystem, new Path(sourceFullPath), destFileSystem, new Path(destinationFullPath), true, sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration, null)
```

and afterwards use

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(yourConfiguration)
fs.copyToLocalFile(true, destinationFullPath, localFilePath)
```