# How to save Spark RDD to local filesystem

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, dataframe, hive

can i save a file into the local system with the `saveAsTextFile` syntax ?
This is how i'm writing the syntax to save a file:   `insert_df.rdd.saveAsTextFile("<local path>")`

when i'm trying to do this i'm getting error as no permissions, but i have all the permissions to that specific local path, looks like it is treating the file as HDFS file.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you should try `"file:///local path"` instead of `"/local path"`.

Comment: i'm running this on cluster, do i have to mention any host name ?? or just the "file:///path" would be enough ??

Comment: i mean host name before the path

Comment: I don't use saveAsTextFile, when I want to save the content of an RDD to an text file on my Cluster. Maybe you have to use collect(), but this is not a good Idea on a huge RDD. And if it works, you will get the same number of text Files as the number of Partitions of the RDD. What im am using is in Java the following: `rdd.toLocalIterator().forEachRemaining(x -> bw.write(x.toString())` where bw is a BufferedWriter.

Comment: It is similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31239161/save-a-spark-rdd-to-the-local-file-system-using-java)

Answer (score 0):

The following code works fine:

```
  val outputFilePath = "file:////home/opsdev/SDG/output/"

  DF.repartition(1)
    .write.mode.option("sep", "|")
    .option("header", "true")
    .option("escape", "\"")
    .option("quoteAll", "true")
    .csv(outputFilePath)
```

And dont forget to run in local mode.