# unable to save rdd on local filesystem on windows 10

Tags: windows, scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a scala/spark program that is used to validate xmls file in an input directory and then writes the report to another input parameter (local filesystem path to write report to).

As per the requirements from stakeholders this program is to run on local machines hence I am using spark in local mode.
Till now things were fine, i was using the code below to save my report to a file

```
dataframe.repartition(1)
    .write
    .option("header", "true")
    .mode("overwrite")
    .csv(reportPath)
```

However this required winutils to be installed/configured on the machines running my program.

Given we use cloudera updates very often, there was an overhead of changing winutils after evry update as we would be updating the jars to the latest version in our pom file. Hence, I have been asked to remove the dependency on winutils

On a quick google search and  after coming across [How to save Spark RDD to local filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40226326/how-to-save-spark-rdd-to-local-filesystem)
I decided to change the above pice of code to

```
val outputRdd = dataframe.rdd
val count = outputRdd.count()
println("\nCount is: " + count + "\n")
println("\nOutput path is: " + reportPath + "\n")
outputRdd.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile(reportPath)
```

However, on running the code I am now getting this error

```
Count is: 15


Output path is: C:\\codingdir\\test\\report

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobContextImpl.<init>(Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf;Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/JobID;)V from class org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapRedWriteConfigUtil
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapRedWriteConfigUtil.createJobContext(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:178)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.write(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1096)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1094)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1094)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopDataset(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1094)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$4.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1067)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$4.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1032)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$4.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1032)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1032)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$1.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:958)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:958)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:958)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:957)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$1.apply$mcV$sp(RDD.scala:1499)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$1.apply(RDD.scala:1478)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$1.apply(RDD.scala:1478)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.saveAsTextFile(RDD.scala:1478)
    at com.optus.dcoe.hawk.XmlParser$.delayedEndpoint$com$optus$dcoe$hawk$XmlParser$1(XmlParser.scala:120)
    at com.optus.dcoe.hawk.XmlParser$delayedInit$body.apply(XmlParser.scala:16)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)
    at com.optus.dcoe.hawk.XmlParser$.main(XmlParser.scala:16)
    at com.optus.dcoe.hawk.XmlParser.main(XmlParser.scala)
```

I have tried changing the value of reportPath varible to
C:\codingdir\test\report
file://C:/codingdir/test/report
file://C:/codingdir/test/report

and other values as suggested on

- [Write RDD as textfile using Apache Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30993655/write-rdd-as-textfile-using-apache-spark)
- [How to save Spark RDD to local filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40226326/how-to-save-spark-rdd-to-local-filesystem)
- [How to access local files in Spark on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30520176/how-to-access-local-files-in-spark-on-windows)

and other links but I am still getting same error

I have found these articles about java.lang.IllegalAccessError but not sure how do i get around this error:

- https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/java-lang-illegalaccesserror-how-to-resolve-illegal-access-error/
- [java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076414/java-lang-illegalaccesserror-tried-to-access-method)

Can someone please help me in resolving this?

Env variable HADOOP_HOME pertaining to winutls has been removed.
winutils entry has been removed from PATH variable
I am using java 8 on windows 10 (all the users of the program would be on similar laptops)
Spark version is 2.4.0-cdh6.2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found out the issue,
It was caused by some unwanted mapreduce related dependencies which have now been removed and I have moved to another error now